# How To extract the content of TinyMCE text as HTML?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tinymce, content-management-system

I'm using TinyMCE, I just want to extract the content as HTML tags so that I can use them else where I have tried many things with no good results at all. How can I do so?

Or if you can tell me a way to get to the id's in the JavaScript CDN or something?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, TinyMCE will only update the underlying `<textarea>` when you perform a standard form submission.

If you want to get the current data from the editor at any point in time you need to use the `get()` API call within TinyMCE:

https://www.tinymce.com/docs/api/tinymce/root_tinymce/#get

You pass the ID of the `<textarea>` as a String to this method call:

```
tinymce.get('mytextbox')
```

You can also use the `activeEditor` method to get a handle on the currently active editor:

```
tinymce.activeEditor
```

...but this won't work if the user has not interacted with the editor or if there are multiple on the page and you need to target a specific editor instance other than the one with which the user is currently interacting.

If you want to force TinyMCE to update the underlying `<textarea>` you can call the `triggerSave` method:

https://www.tinymce.com/docs/api/tinymce/root_tinymce/#triggersave

This will make every TinyMCE instance update its underlying `<textarea>` at which point you could interact with the underlying `<textarea>` confident it contains the latest data from the editor.

Answer (score 0):

Your instance of TinyMCE should have a text area associated with it somewhere. For example, the one located on the page here:

https://www.tinymce.com/

has a textarea with an id of `mce_0`.

If you right click and inspect the page, you can see the HTML structure and find it below the TinyMCE divs. You'll want to start inspecting things to see how they work :)

So with jquery:

```
$('#mce_0').val()
```

And with pure javascript:

```
document.getElementById('mce_0').value
```

Just a matter of getting the textarea :)